# Update entire object in an array of objects in Vuex store with Vue.set()?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, state, vuex, flux

I have a form that needs to reactively update an entire object in an array of objects in a state mutation. I know `Vue.set()` works well for updating a single property, but I'm curious if it works to just update the full object. Something like this:

```
Vue.set(state.objects, obj.id, newObject)
```

The use case would be for a form update where the properties that are modified would be inconsistent. I may also just be misunderstanding `Vue.set()` altogether. The docs are extremely brief on this, saying only:

> When adding new properties to an Object, you should either:
>
> Use Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123), or
>
> Replace that Object with a fresh one. For example, using the object spread syntax we can write it like this:

```
state.obj = { ...state.obj, newProp: 123 }
```

Any advice on the best way to go about this would be greatly appreciated!

I was previously updating the object by finding the index and replacing it, but that seemed to lack reactivity. Example:

```
let index = state.objects.findIndex(o => o.id === obj.id)
if (index !== -1) {
  state.objects[index] = new Object(obj)
  return
}
state.objects.push(new Object(obj))
```

Comment: if you are looking to update an existing object, try using the `splice()` method instead. `state.objects.splice(index, 1, newObject)`

Comment: Thanks! That works really well.

Comment: Awesome to hear!

Comment: @TJWeems that worked very well for me. Thanks!